# How to explicitly summon and use Functor for function

Tags: scala, scala-cats

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
import cats.Functor
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.instances.function._

val list1 = List(1, 2)

val list2 = Functor[List].map(list1)(i => i + 1)
```

But things don't work so smoothly for functions,

```
val f1 = (i: Int) => i.toString
val f2 = (s: String) => s
```

And we have to resort to type trickery,

```
scala> type TTT[A] = Int => A
// defined type alias TTT

scala> val ff = Functor[TTT].map(f1)(f2)
// ff: TTT[String] = scala.Function1$$Lambda$607/69160933@3a689738
```

Well... Is there a more direct way to solve this, as this tends to get very tedious for complex functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write

```
val ff = Functor[Int => ?].map(f1)(f2)
```

if you [add](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) `addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.9.7")` to `build.sbt`.

Or you can import functor syntax `import cats.syntax.functor._` and then write with type ascription

```
val ff = (f1: TTT[String]).map(f2)
```

or with explicit type annotation

```
val f1: TTT[String] = (i: Int) => i.toString
val ff = f1.map(f2)
```

Comment: As per this answer, I would advise using kind-projector if you can. Its fairly standard across functional projects and even if people aren't familiar with it the syntax feels fairly natural/self explanatory

Comment: @HugoFirth `kind-projector` looks good. I am not sure if I remember correctly but didn't Erik Osheim decide to transition to Rust few months back ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh eh? no, I think you have Erik confused with someone else. regardless, `kind-projector` is a cornerstone of the Typelevel ecosystem, so even if Erik were to disappear, `kind-projector` would certainly continue to exist, there are lots of other people in Typelevel.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you summon the type class instance explicitly in the first place? cats includes syntax support for functor, so there's no need for that.

```
import cats.syntax.functor._
import cats.instances.function._
val mul4 = ((a: Int) => a * 2).map(_ * 2)
```

In order for this to work, you'll need the `-Ypartial-unification` compiler flag (`scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"` if you're using sbt). This flag is likely to be enabled by default in future scala versions.

Comment: There is a need to summon the `implicit` when you want to do something to the `implicit` itself.